# nftables + Almalinux (CPanel): Help creating rules

Tags: nftables, cpanel

I need help creating rules.  According to CPanel firewall-d broke migrating from CentOS > Alma Linux.  They no longer supported CentOS so I bit the bullet finally and migrated.  Everything went swimmingly until I found out about firewall-d because all my ipsets and the process by which I add new offenders into my block lists broke.  They suggested I move to nftables.  After looking into it and trying a few things I can't figure out exactly what I'm looking for.

I wanted to add the timeout elements (1 Day) like CPanel does with cphulk.

I experimented a bit by:

```
nft add table inet filter
nft add set inet filter jerk_ips { type ipv4_addr \; }
nft add chain inet filter jerk_ips '{ type filter hook input priority 0 ; }'
nft add rule inet filter jerk_ips ip saddr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx drop
```

- xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = some offending IP address

I'm just super confused as to how this all works.  I've read a bunch online but it assumes you know hot all this nested stuff works which is then where I read about "sets" and it's "sets" where you can put a flag like called "timeout".

My end result is to simply parse my log files like I always did, find offenders, block them but since I'm redoing everything I thought I'd add a 24 hour / 1 day automatic removal since I believe it easier to do so with nftables now than it would have been with fireall-cmd in firewall-d.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Element_timeouts) has an almost complete example:

> Example, with per-element timeout:
>
> ```shell
> % nft add table inet myfilter
> % nft add set inet myfilter myset {type ipv4_addr\; flags timeout\; }
> % nft add element inet myfilter myset {10.0.0.1 timeout 10s }
> % nft list ruleset
> table inet myfilter {
>   set myset {
>       type ipv4_addr
>       flags timeout
>       elements = { 10.0.0.1 timeout 10s expires 8s}
>   }
> }
> ```

Adding to the set definition `flags timeout ;` (and possibly proper shell escaping/quoting) enables element automatic expiration.

Here the timeout was provided when adding the element: stated right after the element following the syntax in [`nft(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#ELEMENTS):

```
{add | create | delete | get } element [family] table set { ELEMENT[, ...] }


ELEMENT := key_expression OPTIONS [: value_expression]
OPTIONS := [timeout TIMESPEC] [expires TIMESPEC] [comment string]
TIMESPEC := [numd][numh][numm][num[s]]
```

It's also possible to have a *default* timeout: when the timeout is not provided along the added element, the default timeout is applied. in addition to `flags timeout`, the default timeout value has to be given when creating the set, as per the syntax in the [`nft(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#SETS):

> ```
> add set [family] table set 
>     { type type | typeof expression ; [flags flags ;] [timeout timeout ;] [gc-interval gc-interval ;] [elements = { element[, ...] } ;] [size size ;] [comment comment ;] [policy 'policy ;] [auto-merge ;] }
> {delete | list | flush} set [family] table set
> list sets [family]
> delete set [family] table handle handle
> {add | delete} element [family] table set { element[, ...] }
> ```

So instead of OP's:

> ```
> nft add set inet filter jerk_ips { type ipv4_addr \; }
> ```

use (here adding quotes to avoid shell interpretation and thus removing multiple `\`):

```
nft add 'set inet filter jerk_ips { type ipv4_addr ; flags timeout ; timeout 1d ; }'
```

to get a default timeout of 1 day. It's still possible to add some elements with a different timeout when needed following what was shown first.

Here 1d = 24h = 1440m = 86400s